# What technology/methodology can I use to hot deploy changes in a J2EE environment?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, drools

I work on a piece of software that includes a payroll system and payroll rules have a tendency to change, especially when it comes to taxes. My company has branches all across the U.S.A. and almost every state has their own rules for state (and sometimes local) taxes. As such, I need to be able to update the logic for each state at a moments notice. I need to be able to do this without having to push a new version of the whole application. I also need to be able to access a database and we are using JBoss as our AS. Currently we are using an older version of [Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools) and it is has been working but it feels like a hack to solve this problem.

I have been reading a little bit about [OSGI](http://www.osgi.org/Main/HomePage) but it sounds like it might be overkill.

What other options are available?

Comment: What is wrong with Drools? OSGI requires an architecture planed for OSGI. Rule engines are designed for change during runtime. OSGI for replacement (features or bugs). That said I've to restart eclipse (OSGI) after each update.

Answer (score 3):

It depends a lot on what kind of logic needs to be deployed without restart. If it's just business rules, drools sound like a reasonable choice to me.

If it's more than that, and including some technical level logic you could try a scripting language like groovy. Its GroovyScriptEngine is able to monitor file changes and recompile code when needed.

Finally there are tools like LiveRebel which allow smooth redeployment of basically any Java application. This is a commercial tool

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you say that the implementation with Drools you use "feels like a hack". Drools is designed from the ground up to allow hot (re)deployment of business rules. You can store your business rules in a rules repository (like Guvnor), in a database, in the filesystem or generate the rules on the fly. You can access the rules using your own code or you can use one of the knowledge agents Drools ships with.

At runtime, when rules are redeployed, Drools automatically handles the knowledge base update and hot deploy them. The changes are visible and safely propagated on any existing session, meaning no need to recreate sessions or reload existing facts (data).

Maybe if you can detail what feels wrong about it, we can point you in the right direction. Also, you mentioned you are using an older version of Drools. Which version is that?

Comment: We are using Drools 4.0.2. I guess the reason that it feels like a hack is because I want something more java like. I attended a drools lecture at a [NFJS](http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/home/main) conference and the speaker described functions and said that if you find yourself using them a lot, your not using drools correctly. (or something close to that) Anyways, I find myself using them a lot because they are more java like.

Comment: Drools 4 is indeed a very old version of Drools, but the idea is the same. The new versions make writing rules a lot easier and more intuitive also. There is a fundamental difference between functions (imperative algorithms) and rules (declarative behavior). So if you are using more functions than rules, chances are you are either using the wrong model for the tool or the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Liverebel 2.0 is your product - see http://liverebel.com